# regex that matches all lines that contains a specific word <python>

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match every line that contains the word "Freezer". The catch is everything on that line should match except for the word Freezer. So for example based on our sample data below, the first line should return "Apple" only excluding the keyword Freezer. Same goes with the 3rd and 5th line. I have gone as far as selecting the line by using this regex:

```
^.*Freezer.*
```

It selects the 1st, 3rd and 5th lines but couldn't figure out how to exclude "Freezer" on the match.

```
Apple Freezer   - True
Laptop 15.4" 120GB HD   -   False
Orange Freezer - Banana Mango Left AC   -   True
Prince Yellow Bed   -    False
Grapes Eyes - Fridge/Freezer   - True
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Everything should match except` This can be done only if _Freezer_ is at the end of the line. Two steps: if `Freezer` in line, Replace all `Freezer\s*` with nothing. You're left with a line without Freezer.

Comment: I would advise you to store the result in a variable first. Then, you replace all of the *Freezer* sub-strings in the variable with *blank*.

Comment: Another option is to _split_ on freezer. If the array size > 1 you matched, and all the elements don't contain freezer.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
regex = r"^.+?(?=Freezer)"
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  .+?       : 1 or more any charcter but newline, not greedy
  (?=       : start positive lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we have after
    Freezer : literally
  )         : end lookahead
```